# arttribute error with dict not finding object even though its in the dict

Tags: python

when i run the code and i get to the question its gets and error claiming that the object i am calling on is not in the dict even though it what i want to do is add 5 to the social point as seen in the class player. is there anyway to solve this or rewrite it? thanks in advance.

where the values of the player are stored

```
 ##### player setup #####
 class player():
def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.gender = ''
    self.classyear4 = ''
    self.sociaal = 25
    self.educatie = 25
    self.emoties = 25
    self.location = 'c16'
    self.game_over = False


    myPlayer = player()
```

the code that gets the error

```
myPlayer2 = {}
question5 ={"ga je naar de stad met vrienden of ga je naar huis?\n":["ja", "nee"]}
for question5, valid_answers  in question5.items():
    correct = False
    error_msg =""
    if valid_answers == None:
        answer = input(question5 + '\n>')
        myPlayer[question5] = answer
    else:
        while correct == False:
            answer = input(error_msg+question5+'\n>')
            if answer.strip().lower() == "ja" in valid_answers: ###the prbleem is that the code cant tell the diffrence between the two anwsers because in its eyes there both valid anwsers so it just runs the first one and not the one were you say no###
                print("je gaat mee, thuis heb ik toch niks te doen.\n")
                myPlayer[question5] = answer
                correct = True
                myPlayer.sociaal += 5
                print("je hebt 5 sociale punten gekregen")
                print(myPlayer.sociaal)
            elif answer.strip().lower() == "nee" in valid_answers: ###so fix it so that its able to tell the diffrence between the two anwsers and so that it works after that you add that you get point for the action and that those point are shown good luck###
                print("je gaat naar huis lekker netflixen.\n")
                myPlayer[question5] = answer
                correct = True

            else:
                error_msg = ("probeer het opnieuw \n")
                for key, value in myPlayer.items():
                    print("{}:{}".format(key, value))
```

the error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Sekou\Documents\school simulator game\aloysiusgame.py", line 382, in <module>
myPlayer.sociaal += 5
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sociaal'

C:\Users\Sekou\Documents\school simulator game>
```

Comment: You appear to have done `myPlayer = {}` or something similar somewhere else in your code.  `myPlayer` is no longer a `player` object, but now refers to a `dict` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at how you are creating the myPlayer variable. I see that myPlayer2 was created as a dict, was that supposed to have been myPlayer? It looks like you are interchanging the methods for setting data on myPlayer. In python, dictionary keys are not addressable with object dot-notation, like you could in something like javascript. So,

```
foo = {}
foo['my_key'] = 'bar' # this will work
foo.my_attribute = 'baz' # this will fail
```

Python classes can use dot-notation for addressing attributes. Given that you have a `player` class created above, I believe what you are looking for would be:

```
myPlayer = player()
...
myPlayer.question5 = answer
...
myPlayer.sociaal += 5
```

Comment: could you maybe elaborate more on you anwser because i am having trouble understanding. because from what i understand setting the values by dot-notation in the player class it wrong and what i should do is use the class than acesss it by use of the key and than setting its value? and the anwser belowe are the problem areas and what should be changed? and myplayer2 was not supposed to be a dict it was just anwser system for the player asking his gender that should probaby be changed sloppy on my end.

Comment: It's perfectly viable to set values on the attributes of your player object. Since you have the class defined, I would recommend creating and setting the myPlayer variable using the dot-notation for all get and set operations. In the error message you pasted, the myPlayer object is a dictionary, and not of type player. That is why it says the object has no attribute 'sociaal'

Comment: after trying to digest your answer a billion times and trying to make sense of it (i'm a beginner) I have finally solved this issue that I have been struggling with for 2 weeks now. so I tried doing the rubber duck method by explaining your answer to a teddy bear and a few minutes later it finally clicked thank you so much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
myPlayer[question5] = answer
```

`myPlayer` isn't a `dict`, so using `[...]` won't work. If you use `getattr` instead, this should work:

```
setattr(myPlayer, question5, answer)
```